# Vue components in Inertia with Laravel seems to load twice

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

With a newly created Laravel with Inertia and Vue project, I have an error that it runs code inside my vue components twice.

For a simple test demo, I have a [Test.vue](https://github.com/ekstremedia/laravel-inertia/blob/main/resources/js/Pages/Test.vue), with this code

```
<template>
<div>
    TEST
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "Test",
    mounted() {
        console.log('test')
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Route in web.php:

```
Route::get('/test', array(App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController::class, 'test'));
```

In controller:

```
    public function test(): Response
    {
        return Inertia::render('Test');
    }
```

When I go to the route /test, it echoes out 'test' twice on mounted in my console. In more advanced components which calls APIs and such, also calls them twice.

[image]

I suspect maybe my project is set up wrongly, in [app.blade.php](https://github.com/ekstremedia/laravel-inertia/blob/main/resources/views/app.blade.php) or [app.js](https://github.com/ekstremedia/laravel-inertia/blob/main/resources/js/app.js) but cannot figure it out.

I followed the guides on https://inertiajs.com/server-side-setup and https://inertiajs.com/client-side-setup to set this up.

My source code is here: https://github.com/ekstremedia/laravel-inertia

Edit: It seems to only echo out twice in the first component I load. If I in that component link to another component, and go there, it doesn't load that twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that this is solved by modifying your app.js file in your resources directory thus:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { App as InertiaApp, plugin as InertiaPlugin } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue'


Vue.use(InertiaPlugin)

new Vue({
    render: (h) =>
        h(InertiaApp, {
            props: {
                initialPage: JSON.parse(app.dataset.page),
                resolveComponent: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}`).default,
            },
        }),
}).$mount(app);
```

Your problem seems to have been in how you initialized your inertia app.